# Ckeditor: detect upload has finished

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to make changes in ckeditor textarea (via ajax) after any image upload. So, I need to detect when image has been fully uploaded and then get actual content with that uploaded image and send via ajax to server side for further actions.

My editor configuration options are:

`var options =`    `{`
`language: "<?= LOCALE_CODE ?>",`
`height: 300,`
`toolbar: "Basic",`
`uiColor: "#f5f5f5",`
`format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4;pre;address;div",`
`filebrowserUploadMethod: "form",`
`filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "/<?= LOCALE_CODE ?>/file/upload?command=QuickUpload&type=Images",`
`filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: null`
`};`

Is it possible?
I've tried to use *fileUploadResponse* event, but is's introduced only in ckeditor v 4.5, I have an older version, 4.1.

Comment: Can you update to CkEditor 4.5?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot update. I would like to know is there any alternative solution for fileUploadResponse event in older ckeditor versions.